# Problems In PyGame By Zooming A Background Picture

Tags: image, python-3.x, pygame, zooming

I was trying to make a game that has a world map at the background. In this game the user could have been able to zoom the picture or drag the picture by clicking the mouse and moving it. First, I tried to add the zooming feature but strange things happen when the user clicks the mouse in order to zoom the picture. The picture is divided into squares. Here is the picture and my code. 
This is the picture:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQhfX.jpg [1]:

This is what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdlqt.jpg

```
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import *
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 800
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 32)
img = pygame.image.load("/Users/Esat/Desktop/map.jpg")
img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(WIDTH,HEIGHT))

while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        button_down = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if button_down == (1,0,0):
            print("Clicked")
            WIDTH = WIDTH+10
            HEIGHT = HEIGHT+10
            img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
        windowSurface.blit(img, (0, 0)) 
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you keep altering an image repeatedly things can get funky pretty quick. I find it best to keep a copy of the original and make all your scale changes based off that one. The following is your code fixed:

```
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import *
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 800
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 32)
originalImg = pygame.image.load("map.jpg")
img = pygame.transform.scale(originalImg,(WIDTH,HEIGHT))

while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        button_down = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if button_down == (1,0,0):
            #print("Clicked")
            WIDTH = WIDTH+10
            HEIGHT = HEIGHT+10
            img = pygame.transform.scale(originalImg, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
        windowSurface.blit(img, (0, 0)) 
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.flip()
```